# Slightly incorrect info in the recommendation letter

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter

Recently, when my coach submitted his recommendation letter, it mentioned that I was captain since junior year. However, I was nominated during spring time of my sophomore year, so I put down varsity captain since sophomore year. Is this a cause for concern?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will these "errors" in my advisor's letter raise red flags when I apply for academic faculty positions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48154/will-these-errors-in-my-advisors-letter-raise-red-flags-when-i-apply-for-acad). Not a perfect match, but still could be answering the essence. Also, see several other relevant question under the [tag:recommendation-letter].

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate. However, based on previous answers from others, the answer is no, it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody will care about the marginal difference, and neither should you: This isn't going to make a difference in your application. Feel free to move your brain onto more fruitful topics :-)